# How to detect end of "halfway" 4-finger-pinch on iPad

Tags: objective-c, gestures, touches

I am stuck on this problem:
When i use the four finger pinch (like the home button) to close the app, but only do it "halfway" (the app window gets smaller etc.) and then release it so that it does not close but stays open.
It seems that the `touchesBegan` method gets called that I have implemented, but the `touchesEnded` method is not getting called at any point. Also `viewDidAppear` etc. will not get called. Problem is that `userInteraction` is set to `NO` in `touchesBegan` and thus the app is stuck, as `touchesEnded` is not called.

Is there any other way to detect the end of a "halfway" pinch?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the touch gets cancelled. If you subscribe to `touchesEnded:withEvent:` you should always also subscribe to `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`, because there are much more reasons a touch might gets cancelled which you should handle appropriately.